# Add children viewController himself in the hierachy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a question about ViewControllers hierarchy.

I have a parent VC which I'd like to add a child view controller like the UIAlertView, I mean, I don't want the parent view controller execute the methods to add a children View：
 `Controller:addChildViewController`,`addSubview:self`,`didMoveToParentViewController:viewcontroller`, instead of that the children will run them over the parent:

This is the child init method:

```
- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewcontroller
{
    self = [self initWithNibName:@"DCYGarmenSelectionViewController" bundle:NULL];
    if (self) {
        [viewcontroller addChildViewController:self];
        [viewcontroller.view addSubview:self.view];
        [self didMoveToParentViewController:viewcontroller];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the view will Appear method I set the position of the view.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.width/2,     self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height/2);
}
```

So, the parent just run:

```
  DCYGarmenSelectionViewController *child = [[DCYGarmenSelectionViewController alloc]initWithParentViewController:self];
  child.delegate = self;
```

My question is, do you consider this is ok or this is an big mistake.

Thanksssss!!!!!

Comment: have you test these code your self?`- (id)initWithParentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewcontroller`,there are some code smell in this method ,you add `self` to it's parent but self initialization progress is not complete.

Comment: self.view does not exist in the init method. You'll have to add it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: johnMa, I forgot to write the - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil method, but this is created by default. But the code it's working :)

Comment: George Green The self.view is created due this is loaded from a nib. In fact I have checked it debugging.